# How to customize bibliography label?

Tags: bibliographies, formatting

I would like to completely manually customize the label of my bibliography. I wasn't able to find a satisfactory answer after some searching on the web and here. I want to make a command such that, if in the `biblio.bib` file I put

```
@book{book1,
title = {Théorie de l'intégration},
author = {Briane, Marc and Pagès, Gilles},
label = {BP}
}

@book{book2,
title = {Histoires hédonistes de groupes et de géométries},
author = {Caldero, Philippe and Germoni, Jérôme},
label = {H2G2}
}
```

then I would the following code works like the picture below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  style=alphabetic,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\bibliography{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
  Please see the first book~\autocite[p.~31]{book1} and the second~\autocite[p.~134]{book2}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: always show a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: Edited as you recommended it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `shorthand` field is for. The `label` field is only used as a fallback when the labelling algorithm fails. But the `shorthand` field overrides the generated label entirely.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
title = {Théorie de l'intégration},
author = {Briane, Marc and Pagès, Gilles},
shorthand = {BP}
}

@book{book2,
title = {Histoires hédonistes de groupes et de géométries},
author = {Caldero, Philippe and Germoni, Jérôme},
shorthand = {H2G2}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  style=alphabetic,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Please see the first book~\autocite[p.~31]{book1} and the second~\autocite[p.~134]{book2}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!